# Convert horizontal tabs to vertical tabs using mat-tab

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-tab

I am using mat-tab-group to display tabs horizontally. It looks ok on computer screen. But on mobile screen, it does not look very neat. Is there a way to convert it into vertical tab list if its mobile size screen?

```
   <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <mat-icon ngClass="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
        <span>Account Summary</span>
    </ng-template>
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <app-summary
        [loanNumber]="loanNumber"
      ></app-summary>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
      .
      .      
      .
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the basic functionality with css and "shadow-piercing"

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tab-vert

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-labels {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .mat-tab-group {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .mat-ink-bar {
    height: 100%;
    left: 100% !important;
  }
  .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working at my end! even not updating css of components